# in PHP pdo how can i use an incremental identifier

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have the following challenge:

a "Tasks" table:

```
tasksId     int
listId      int
taskOrder   float
```

in case i want to move all the tasks from list 2 to list 3 i would do something like:

```
// pseodo code //

@lastTaskOrder = last task order in list 3
loop - {
UPDATE tasks SET taskOrder = @lastTaskOrder + 1, listId = 3 WHERE listId = 2;        
@lastTaskOrder++
}
```

thus the taskOrder stays unique.

in case i want to move all the tasks from list 2 to the *beginning* of list 3 i would do something like:

```
// pseodo code //

@firstTaskOrder = first task order in list 3
@delta = @firstTaskOrder / @numberOfTasksToMove
UPDATE tasks SET taskOrder = @firstTaskOrder + @delta, listId = 3 WHERE listId = 2;        
@firstTaskOrder = @firstTaskOrder + @delta
```

is it possible with mySQL + PDO + PHP?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: yes.

Longer answer involves some code.  To update your list_ids and increment them based on the highest current value in the old list, I had to use a subquery with a window function:

```
UPDATE tasks
SET list_id = :toList,
    task_order = 
                (SELECT MAX(task_order) from tasks where list_id = :toList) 
                + t2.task_sort_order
FROM ( SELECT task_id, 
    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY list_id order by task_order) 
                AS task_sort_order 
    FROM tasks ) t2 
WHERE tasks.task_id = t2.task_id AND tasks.list_id = :fromList
```

**Edit** This is heavily edited from the first version.  I've thrown away all the PHP in favor of just showing the SQL.  I changed the column names because my version of Postgres was complaining about the camel-case names.

Comment: Now that I've thought about it, we can definitely reduce this to a single query.  I have to break out my psql console...

Comment: thank you for your reply. it seems that the second Query changes all the taskOrder to the same number. maybe i did something wrong..

Comment: Yup.  That's how you described the functionality in your post and in your pseudocode.

Comment: you are right - i wasn't clear ;-). i revised my post. the idea was that the taskOrder will still be unique so if i had those order numbers in list one (1,2,3) and those numbers in list two (1,2,3) the new list will have (1,2,3,4,5,6).

Comment: I see you came up with a cleaner solution, although you have to do a query to get the start value.  I've come up with the edited statement above.

Comment: it is way above my SQL level to understand this. i'll study the query to try. I am not sure there is a row_number method in mySQL though. its absence came up during my google sessions. anyway, thank you.

Comment: Use what works that you can confidently maintain.  I posted this because it was an interesting puzzle and it took me a while to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

this proved to be easier than i thought it would be.
It took me 2 hours but i got it figured out:

```
SET @start=100;
SET @delta=1.5;
UPDATE tasks SET taskOrder = @start:= (@start+@delta), listId = 3
WHERE listId=2
ORDER BY taskOrder
```

I PDOed this query with the correct values